# jQuery - unrecognized expression: li:nth-child?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
(function (){

    var num = parseInt($('body').attr('data-site')) + 1,
        theul = $(".submenu li:nth-child(" + num + ") a"),
        newNum = num - 1,
        theNewUl = $(".submenu li:nth-child(" + newNum + ") a");

        console.log(theul);
        theul.addClass('activex');
        console.log(theNewUl);
        theNewUl.addClass('lastsl');

})();
```

Hello, when I try to run this script console says:

"Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li:nth-child"

Althoung I linked the jQuery source before this script,

thanks for anwsers

Comment: Is `$('body').attr('data-site')` actually convertible to a number?

Comment: `console.log(num, ".submenu li:nth-child(" + num + ") a");`

Comment: this is probably due to the fact that 'num' is not an actual number, make sure the parsing is correct and you actually have a number in 'num'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use `.data("foo")` in favor of `.attr("data-foo")`.
2. You can use [the `:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). It's zero-based, which is what you seem to want.
3. You do not need to call `.addClass()` on a separate line.
4. You *must* use the radix `10` when you use `parseInt()`, or numbers like `08` will be interpreted as octal.
5. You need to make sure that `num` actually contains a number, or `parseInt()` will return `NaN` and that will break your following code.
6. Prefix variables that contain a jQuery object with a `$`. It's a useful convention to follow.

Try:

```
var num = parseInt($('body').data("site"), 10),
    $theul = $(".submenu li:eq(" + num + ") a").addClass('activex'),
    $theNewUl = $(".submenu li:eq(" + (num-1) + ") a").addClass('lastsl');
```

Comment: Worth noting that `:eq` and `:nth-child` are very different things. Their documentation highlights the fact that `nth-child` is 1-based, but (more importantly) it functions differently: `nth-child` retrieves any elements that are the nth child of their parents. This can be several elements depending on your selector. `eq` retrieves the single element at that index in your selection.